# How to select an ROI from a 2D frame when condition is not met?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to select a region of interest (ROI) from a 2D frame. An ROI of size 15x15 is selected from a 50x50 frame.

In the beginning, we check if a 15x15 ROI can fit inside the frame at a given pixel location to make sure the ROI doesn't cross the boundary. However, when the condition is not met, I want to select a 15x15 ROI but with zero values for all the pixels that are outside of the frame boundary. See the diagram below as an example of what I am trying to do:

For x = 11 and y = 4, the ROI will be selected

[image: ROI_when_condition_is_met]

However, when the pixel is at x = 1 and y 1, a section of the ROI will be outside of the frame. In this case, I want to fill the empty region with zeros values

[image: ROI_when_condition_is_not_met]

For a given pixel, this pixel will always be the centre of the ROI

That's the code that I am working on, it only selects ROIs when they can fit inside the frame when the condition is met. When the condition is not met, I want to fill the ROI with zeros.

```
import numpy as np
row = 50
column = 50
num_data_points = 2
frame = np.zeros([row, column, num_data_points])

    def ROI(x, y):
        row_address = x
        column_address = y
        roi_radius = 7
        roi_diameter = 2 * roi_radius + 1
    
        # check if the ROI of size 15x15 can fit inside the 50x50 frame 
        if (row_address-roi_radius > 0) and (column_address-roi_radius > 0) and (row_address+roi_radius < row) and (column_address+roi_radius < column):
            # select a 15x15 ROI from the frame matrix
            ROI_on = frame[row_address-roi_radius:row_address+roi_radius+1,
                            column_address-roi_radius:column_address+roi_radius+1, 0] 
    
        else:
            new_roi = np.zeros([15, 15])
            # select all neighbouring pixels and make a 15x15 ROI with zero values for other pixels
```

I thought about using np.pad() or concatenate matrix, but not sure which one will be more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
import numpy as np

# generate random frame
frame = np.random.randint(0,10,(50,50))

# padd frame with zeros
n,m = 15,15
padded_frame = np.pad(frame, max([n,m]))

# define center of roi and compute extend
roi_center = (20,20)
bottom = roi_center[0]-int(np.floor(n/2))
top = roi_center[0] + int(np.ceil(n/2))
left = roi_center[1]- int(np.floor(m/2))
right = roi_center[1] + int(np.ceil(m/2))

roi = padded_frame[bottom: top,left:right]
```